# Probability Density Function with continuous random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ have density 
$$
  f_X(x) 
= \begin{cases}
  \sqrt{3(x+2)}/6 & -2 \leq x \leq 1 \\
  0 & \text{otherwise}. 
  \end{cases}
$$
Find the probability that $X$ is positive.

Would this just be the integral from $0$ to $1$?

Comment: Yes- that would be the answer!

Comment: @user139388 I do not know how to use HTML. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

To find the probability that $X$ is positive implies that $\int^1_0 f_X(x)$ is what we are looking for.Evaluate that integral to get the probability that X is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the density function from 0 to 1, since it will not take any value for x > 1.
I think your answer will be $\displaystyle 1 - \frac{2 \sqrt{2}}{3\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.45567$